# Weird behavior with FQ type names

Tags: javaparser

I'm trying to extract all class/interface type references from a class declarations. I'm getting a weird behavior with FQ names.
Here is a simple example:

```
CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(
  "public class foo extends java.lang.String {}");
cu.stream().
  filter(ClassOrInterfaceType.class::isInstance).
  forEach(System.out::println);
```

the output is:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang
java
```

I was expecting the `java.lang.String` but the others? What does it ever mean that `java.lang` is a `ClassOrInterfaceType`?
I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior, in any case: is there a way to filter out these spurious elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively

```
String s = "class Foo extends java.lang.String {}";
    CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(s);
    cu.findAll(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.class).forEach(cid -> {
        System.out.println(cid.getNameAsString());
        cid.getExtendedTypes().forEach(extType -> System.out.println(extType.getNameAsString()));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

"What does it ever mean that java.lang is a ClassOrInterfaceType?"
You get this result because during parsing the parser is not able to determine whether java.lang is a type or a package.